# Pandas iterating over index and appending remaining rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[1,2,3],'x':[3,2,1]}).set_index('id')
print df
    x
id   
1   3
2   2
3   1
```

I need to iterate the rows, so that for each id, we append the remaining rows, e.g. the output should be:

```
    x
id   
1   3
    2
    1
2   2
    1
3   1
```

**Ideally** *O(n)* solution that generalizes to *m* columns.

Comment: Check my solution, it should also working with multiple columns nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with slice by positions with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for `list of DataFrame`s and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for join all together, last remove second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
comp = [df.iloc[i:] for i in range(len(df.index))]
df = pd.concat(comp, keys=df.index).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

print (df)
    x
id   
1   3
1   2
1   1
2   2
2   1
3   1
```

If need both `level`s is possible add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for set `MultiIndex name`s:

```
df = pd.concat(comp, keys=df.index).rename_axis(('a','b'))
print (df)
     x
a b   
1 1  3
  2  2
  3  1
2 2  2
  3  1
3 3  1
```

EDIT:

First level dont display repeated values, but no values are lost:

```
#change default option multi_sparse=True
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)

     x
a b   
1 1  3
1 2  2
1 3  1
2 2  2
2 3  1
3 3  1
```

Comment: This is almost what I need. Is it possible to have unique index? E.g. value 1 should appear once, and not 3 times in the index?

Comment: There is possible use only `MultiIndex` like `df = pd.concat(comp, keys=df.index).rename_axis(('a','b'))`, but it only show one value of first level.

Comment: @GRS - But by default is not possible have no value in index. Terrible hack is convert all duplicated values to `NaN`s by `df = pd.concat(comp, keys=df.index).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`, and
`df.index = df.index.where(~df.index.duplicated())` but I think it is not what you need.

Comment: Thanks, After renaming I just need to remove the 2nd index column, so that I can transform to 3d data using `panel`

Comment: Yes, then need `df = pd.concat(comp, keys=df.index).rename_axis(('a','b'))` - [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) rename names of first and second levels.

Comment: Do you know a way to delete the last `'b'` index? While preserving the structure of `a`? It seems after `reset_index()` All empty values are filled in

Comment: @GRS - Unfortunately always first level contains all data, check last edit. Only it is not displayed - check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) - `In [20]:`

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
df.groupby(level=0).x.apply(lambda y : (np.arange(y)+1)[::-1]).apply(pd.Series).stack()
Out[320]: 
id   
1   0    3.0
    1    2.0
    2    1.0
2   0    2.0
    1    1.0
3   0    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, this technically answers the question, but it doesn't generalize to more columns. Do you have a simple solution in mind?